How to downgrade the version of python package on ubuntu 24.04?
I have the pip package setuptools whoes version is 68.1.2 but i want to downgrade it to 58.2.0. becaouse my colcon build --symlink-install command is giving error while building ros2 package. In Ubuntu 22.04 we can use command pip3 install setuptools==58.2.0 but this command is showing error in ubuntu  24.04.

Use a venv for installing Python package versions that aren't in the system repos
